# Fail to mount /dev/loop0 during Arch-Linux installation

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I've been trying to install Arch-Linux on my machine, but whenever I try to boot my USB, I get the below errors. Is there a way that I can format the drive from rootfs or a way to fix `loop0 mount`?

```
[ 0.000000] ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width. Defaulting to byte size
::running early hook [udev]
Starting version 243.78-1-arch
::running early hook [archiso_pxe_ndb]
running hook [udev]
::Triggering events...
::running hook [memdisk]
::running hook [archiso]
::running hook [archiso_loop_mnt]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_common]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_ndb]
::running hook [archiso_pxe_http]
::running hook [archisopxe_nfs]
::Mounting '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201911' to '/run/archiso/bootmnt'
Waiting 30 seconds for device /dev/disk/by-label/ARH_201911 ...
::Device '/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201911' mounted successfully.
:: Mounting /run/archiso/cowspace (tmpfs) filesystem, size=256...
:: Mounting '/dev/loop0' to '/run/archiso/sfs/airootfs'
mount: /run/archiso/sfs/airootfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
ERROR; Failed to mount '/dev/loop0'
Falling back to interactive prompt
You can try to fix the problem manually, log out when you are finished
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

Comment: @Łukasz, please stop copy-editing code and logs! You’re making it harder to answer questions and introducing errors of your own. (OK, it’s not a problem here really, but in other circumstances it is. As a general rule, leave code blocks alone if you’re copy-editing.)

Comment: How did you create the [USB flash installation medium](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)? According to the [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=189116) not all methods are known to work so it may be related to that.